# Ubuntu takes a very long time to boot after I dual booted it with win7

Tags: boot

When I have only Ubuntu 16.04,it is very fast and boot time was also very less.Later I installed Windows 7 by dual boot (and repaired GRUB).After that Ubuntu takes a very long time to boot,but Win 7 boots instantly.After running dmesg I am giving the last portion.Please suggest a way to solve it.

```
[    1.884039] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2199.955 MHz
[    1.884048] clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x1fb608875b4, max_idle_ns: 440795310951 ns
[    2.884142] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    8.435701] EXT4-fs (sda6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    8.957627] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[    9.597436] systemd[1]: systemd 229 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN)
[    9.597579] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[    9.605438] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <aniruddha-desktop>.
[   11.912456] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[   11.912556] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[   11.912576] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
[   11.912593] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
[   11.912634] systemd[1]: Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[   11.912757] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[   11.912924] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[   11.913012] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[   11.924129] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[   12.008233] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel...
[   12.064279] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[   12.065064] systemd[1]: Mounting Debug File System...
[   12.065973] systemd[1]: Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
[   12.066093] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[   12.066211] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[   12.066995] systemd[1]: Started Braille Device Support.
[   12.070829] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
[   12.070950] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[   12.071808] systemd[1]: Starting Set console keymap...
[   12.071895] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[   12.071940] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[   12.072165] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[   12.072194] systemd[1]: Reached target Encrypted Volumes.
[   12.073062] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
[   12.073970] systemd[1]: Started Read required files in advance.
[   12.074182] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[   12.075064] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[   12.180764] systemd[1]: Started Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel.
[   12.192320] systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
[   12.419420] systemd[1]: Started Uncomplicated firewall.
[   12.531491] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[   12.531544] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[   12.531566] systemd[1]: Mounted Debug File System.
[   12.987888] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   13.047867] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   13.224567] systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
[   13.248273] systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[   13.249138] systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
[   13.249810] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[   15.717083] EXT4-fs (sda6): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   16.228800] systemd-journald[231]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[   17.079889] intel_rng: Firmware space is locked read-only. If you can't or
               intel_rng: don't want to disable this in firmware setup, and if
               intel_rng: you are certain that your system has a functional
               intel_rng: RNG, try using the 'no_fwh_detect' option.
[   17.588503] coretemp coretemp.0: Using relative temperature scale!
[   17.588523] coretemp coretemp.0: Using relative temperature scale!
[   17.592559] leds_ss4200: no LED devices found
[   17.606422] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[   19.359467] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2: ALC888: SKU not ready 0x411111f0
[   19.359880] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2: autoconfig for ALC888: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[   19.359884] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   19.359887] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   19.359890] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   19.359892] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:    dig-out=0x1e/0x0
[   19.359895] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:    inputs:
[   19.359898] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:      Front Mic=0x19
[   19.359901] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:      Rear Mic=0x18
[   19.359903] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:      Line=0x1a
[   19.372537] input: HDA Intel Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input7
[   19.372647] input: HDA Intel Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
[   19.372729] input: HDA Intel Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
[   21.793830] gpio_ich: GPIO from 462 to 511 on gpio_ich
[   21.880090] audit: type=1400 audit(1488745726.419:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=545 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.880102] audit: type=1400 audit(1488745726.419:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=545 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.880110] audit: type=1400 audit(1488745726.419:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=545 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.880117] audit: type=1400 audit(1488745726.419:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=545 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   22.629383] audit: type=1400 audit(1488745727.167:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=544 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   22.629396] audit: type=1400 audit(1488745727.167:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium" pid=544 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.193542] audit: type=1400 audit(1488745727.731:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/freshclam" pid=675 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   24.466415] audit: type=1400 audit(1488745729.003:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="webbrowser-app" pid=680 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   24.466428] audit: type=1400 audit(1488745729.003:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="webbrowser-app//oxide_helper" pid=680 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   24.585948] audit: type=1400 audit(1488745729.123:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince" pid=671 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  108.290006] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): ens2: link is not ready
[  108.297330] r8169 0000:03:00.0 ens2: link down
[  108.297373] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): ens2: link is not ready
[  267.122970] perf interrupt took too long (2501 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
```

Comment: Do you have a driver installed in Windows that allows you to read/write to Ubuntu EXT4 partitions (like the Paragon driver)? Do you have `fast boot` and `hibernation` disabled in Windows? Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: No,I dont have anything to access ext4 in win7. sudo lshw -c network output:*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: ens2
       version: 01
       serial: 00:1c:c0:40:28:03
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz

Comment: capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:27 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fea20000-fea20fff memory:fea00000-fea1ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enp0s29f7u5
       serial: 02:51:09:08:37:65
       capabilities: ethernet physical

Comment: configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.41 link=yes multicast=yes

Comment: Putting the lshw command into comments makes it very difficult to read. Can you please do the command again, and this time, paste the results into your original question (edit). Then delete your last 3 comments to clean things up a bit. Also, see my answer, below.

Answer (score 1):

I see various errors, some minor, some that might cause slow booting...

## lp driver (minor)

```
[   12.987888] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   13.047867] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
```

In `terminal`...

- `gksudo gedit /etc/modules`
- place a `#` in front of lp to disable non-necessary lp driver

  - change `lp` to this... `#lp`
- save file and quit gedit

## file system errors? (possibly major)

```
[   15.717083] EXT4-fs (sda6): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   16.228800] systemd-journald[231]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
```

Let's check your file system for errors...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda6`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

## IPv6 (possible slowness)

```
[  108.290006] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): ens2: link is not ready
[  108.297330] r8169 0000:03:00.0 ens2: link down
[  108.297373] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): ens2: link is not ready
[  267.122970] perf interrupt took too long (2501 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
```

Set network profile for "Wired Connection", IPv6 tab, Method = `Ignore`

- note: set back to `Automatic` after replacing the r8169 driver and see if this problem is gone

## Ethernet driver (possible slowness, connection problems)

```
network description: Ethernet interface product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
driver=r8169
speed=10Mbit/s
```

- buggy r8169 driver... replace with r8168-dkms
- only 10Mbit speed... bad ethernet cable, or switch/hub

In `terminal`...

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install dkms r8168-dkms`
- `reboot`

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please **vote** by clicking the grey up-arrow icon in the upper-left of my answer, and **accept** my answer by clicking the grey checkmark icon in the upper-left of my answer. Thanks!